# An equivalent for between

Tags: word-request

If we suppose one reference (anchor, fixed point), we have the following sides:

- following
- preceding

Now if we suppose two references (points), what is called the part between them which is homogeneous with the words above?

Is it just "between"?

some examples, however my purpose is general

A---------------B-------------C---------------D-----------E

D and E are following items of C, A and B are preceding items of C.

B, C are .... items of A and D

Another example:

- please select following items of C
- please select preceding items of C
- please select ..... of B and D

Comment: Can you describe more about what "anchor" is? "Between" is probably OK in general.

Comment: anchor is a reference, let me change it to reference

Comment: Like on a graph?

Comment: @user3169 No in general, you say following items, preceding items, do you say between items? or middle items?

Comment: Please put an example sentence together and we all will have a common reference point.

Comment: That which lies between any two points on a line is called a *line segment*. The words "following" and "preceding" imply *directionality*, which is arbitrary, not intrinsic to the line.

Answer (score 3):

B and C are in between A and D.  They are also in the middle of the set as a whole, but it feel a bit awkward to say in the middle of A and D.

To your other examples:

**Please select the items that follow C.  (D,E)**

**Please select the items that precede C. (A,B)**

**Please select the items that are between B and D (C).**

or you can use a progressive tense:

**Please select the items that are following/preceding C.**

I cannot think of any other way to say between two items without adding extra information that may not be correct:

are in the middle of - not quite right.

...items that lie between - still using between.

items which come after B and come before D - way too wordy.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can't we just use ...items that are margined or bounded by?

Comment: Hmmm - we could, but aren't nearly as common.  "margined by" does imply being to the outside, but it is not common at all.  "bound by" feels very much like a mathematical term, but this sense could work: "Please select the items that are bound by B and D."  So, you are correct in that those terms could sub for between pretty cleanly, but they would feel strange due to their rarity.

Comment: As @LucianSava suggested  "bounded items" seems promising.

Answer (score 1):

I realise it's an old question and it already has some good answers, but someone else might get some use from these additional words and phrases.

Depending on context, of course:

- *B and C are flanked by A and D*.
- *B and C are in between A and D*.
- *B and C are (the) intermediates of A and D* **or** *The intermediates of A and D are B and C*.

Also consider *amid*. (For a more literary or even archaic feel, consider *amidst* and *betwixt*.)